# Kicad doesn't generate netlist

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, kicad

I have a schematic in kicad that I have finished working on and would like to begin laying out the PCB. I attempt to generate the netlist for PCBnew, I click generate, I select an output directory, then the annotation window pops up and I select to keep the current annotations. Then nothing happens. There is no netlist file in the output directory, nor do I get any errors that would indicate that something wrong has happened.

Comment: Your description sounds like you are working in PCBNew, and creating a back-annotation file.  You have to be in the schematic editor to make a netllist, which you can then read into PCBNew.

Comment: I'm in Eeschema, not PCBNew, when attempting to generate the netlist.

Answer (score 1):

Just to check that the procedure is clear, you can click on "Tools -> Generate Netlist" menu item as shown below:

[image: Generate Netlist Menu Item]

Then you should get the following window pop-up.  You select the "Pcbnew" tab (selected by default) and click "Generate"

[image: Output Selection]

After this, the directory selection window pops up and you click "Save":

[image: Save netlist]

After you to this, if there is no Netlist in the output directory that you selected, can you attach the schematic you are using and say which version of KiCAD you are using?